# Replace String by List that contains the String

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that has the structure:

`(List[String], String)`

An example of two row could be: ([a,b,c], d) and ([d, e], a)
I want to transform these rows then to ([a,b,c], [d,e]) and ([d, e], [a, b, c])

The column names of the dataframe are "src" and "dst".

How can I approach this problem?

What I've tried:

```
val result = df.map(f => {
  if(df.exists(x => x._1.contains(f._2))) {
    (f._1, df.filter(x => x._1.contains(f._2)).head._1)
  } else {
    (f._1, List(f._2))
  }
}).toDF("src", "dst")
```

However, this solution gives me the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2740)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
>           at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:85)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

There must be a more efficient way?

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: Sure, ill edit the post

Comment: what if you have more than two rows in your dataframe?

Comment: It should just take one eventually, but the first is okay since if there are two, those are identical (that's the way the data is structured)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood from your question and comments above, following can be your solution

Given input `dataframe` as

```
+---------+---+
|src      |dst|
+---------+---+
|[a, b, c]|d  |
|[d, e]   |a  |
+---------+---+
```

You can use `join` and `udf` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val joinExpr = udf((col1: mutable.WrappedArray[String], col2: String) =>  col1.contains(col2))

df.as("t1").join(df.as("t2"), joinExpr($"t1.src", $"t2.dst")).select($"t1.src".as("src"), $"t2.src".as("dst")).show(false)
```

to get the final output as

```
+---------+---------+
|src      |dst      |
+---------+---------+
|[a, b, c]|[d, e]   |
|[d, e]   |[a, b, c]|
+---------+---------+
```

Hope the answer is helpful